# Twig - Replace chars in connected string

Tags: string, replace, twig

How can i replace some chars (Goal is a simple double slash to one slash) in a connected twig string?

```
{{ config_basehost ~ navigationElement.imgSrc }} // Connect 2 Strings
```

Replace works like:

```
{{ config_basehost|replace({"a": "b"}) }} // Replace all "a" with "b"
```

But how can i replace something in a connected string?

```
{{ {{ config_basehost ~ navigationElement.imgSrc }}|replace({"a": "b"}) }} // Output: http://example.com/img/cats.jpg|replace({"a":"b"})
```

As you see, the replace is at the end of my "generated" URL. Same as:

```
{{ config_basehost ~ navigationElement.imgSrc }}|replace({"a": "b"}) // Without bracers
```

The double slashes only occures connecting string 1 with string 2. So, string 1 has a slash at last position inside the string, and string 2 at first position. I could replace the last char or the first char from one of these strings, yeah. But that's not the question :)

Comment: {{ (config_basehost ~ navigationElement.imgSrc)|replace({"a": "b"}) }} - try this.

Comment: Yes, that's it! Post it as an answer, if you like to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{{ (config_basehost ~ navigationElement.imgSrc)|replace({"a": "b"}) }}` - try this. 

Use brackets. Simple :)

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ STRING|replace("en": "ar") }}
```

Replaces all occurrences of 'e' and 'n' in a string

```
{{ STRING|replace({"en": "ar"}) }}
```

Replaces all occurrences of 'en' with ar in a string